# Powershell 2.0 Max Number of Arguments

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

What is the maximum number of arguments a Powershell V2.0 script will accept when invoked from the command line or a batch file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The theoretical max would be 2 GB worth of arguments.  :-)  That comes from the fact that unmapped args in a function map to an Object array (`$args`) and arrays in .NET 2.0/4.0 (with 4.5 installed) can be indexed up to Int32.MaxValue.  From what I understand the actual limit is somewhat lower than that depending on the actual type.  FWIW I can create an array of object 128MB in size in PowerShell.  I think the more realistic limit to the number of arguments are limitations on the command line length.  At one point in time cmd.exe had a [max line length of 8191](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473).  I'm not sure what PowerShell's max is but I would guess it would be similar to cmd.exe's max.  Also, if an external process needs to be started then these shells go through the [CreateProcess API it has a limit of 32,767 characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx) for the command line passed to the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any limitation, how many are you thinking to use?

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a specific use case for this, was just curious if there was a limit (Specifically thinking of the 9 argument limit for batch files).